# Stack Overflow Talent register form looks weird

Tags: bug, design, stack-overflow-talent

Just visited the [**register-page**](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/talent/sign-up?utm_medium=referral&utm_source=so-talent&utm_term=login-page-sign-up&__hstc=104275039.08618631ab1a35ca336e26c095dc491e.1538074902102.1538074902102.1538074902102.1&__hssc=104275039.2.1538074902102&__hsfp=3426730081) of Stack Overflow Business and saw the buggy form.

[image]

I tried with Opera, Chrome and Firefox with a resolution of 2560x1440.
Same everywhere.

Is it just me? 
If not a fix would give a better indication of Stack Overflow I think.

Comment: Just tried it with 1920x1080, its the same...

Comment: Sadly it does, at least on my Laptop. But even if not. I think a resolution 2560 is not that rare to not mention it.

Comment: Not sure 100% what part you're seeing as "buggy", but if it's the box in the middle of the drop down box, I'm getting that too, latest Chrome on Windows 7, resolution of 1680x1050 on one monitor, 1280x1024 on the other. (If you mean something other than the weird box in the drop downs, please explain.)

Comment: Yes the dropdown in the middle and the sign-up button over the reCaptcha.

Comment: Sounds like recaptcha takes too long to load and its `data-style="inline"` is not caught by whatever script should use it. Adding a CSS rule `[data-style=inline]{display:inline}` will make the whole thing look a bit better.

Comment: I noticed it "fixes" itself when You open each dropdown once or twice :P

Comment: where is the handmade red circle ?

Comment: Seems to contain t̵w̵o̵  _three_ distinct bugs: the weird looking dropdown, the recaptcha thing overlapping with the signup button, and the text in the boxes clipping off top and bottom.