# The input box of "Notify Users" in Teams got its baby

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-for-teams

[image]

I ask a question in a Teams, and I just got this overlapping "small input box"

[Chrome 69.0.3497.100](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome), Android 8.1.

Comment: username checks out

Comment: Might be related to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374643/stackoverflow-talent-register-form-looks-weird)

Comment: @o_O I didn't understand "username checks out"?

Comment: @iBug: It's a stock phrase meaning that your username is appropriate for the post you made. In this case, your username is iBug, and you're reporting a bug.